# Output gets erased in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I basically have created this recursive function in python down below which calculates the power reached from another node to the other and finding based on that the radius of coverage of the nodes.

What I want to do is take the output from this function and call the recursive function on it one more time without losing the output that I got and I don't know how to do that.

This is the function below:

```
def find_new_int(node_in_ex, old_inters):
    global Power_Sensitivity
    global copy_of_int_list
    intersection_list_method = []
    for wall_coordinates in lines:
        if intersection_rand_point(wall_coordinates[0], wall_coordinates[1], node_in_ex-1, old_inters) is not False:
            intersection_list_method.append(intersection_rand_point(wall_coordinates[0], wall_coordinates[1], node_in_ex-1, old_inters))
    intersection_list_method = sorted(list(itertools.chain(*intersection_list_method)), key=cal_distance_av)
    for points in intersection_list_method:
        if cal_pow_rec_plndwall(node_in_ex, points) > Power_Sensitivity:
            return intersection_list_method
    for points in intersection_list_method:
        return find_new_int(node_in_ex, points)
```

I want to loop on the intersection_list_method outputed from the first time I ran the function >>IF<< the function didn't return the intersection_list_method in the 3rd line from the bottom.
The problem with what im doing here is that when I call

```
find_new_int(node_in_ex, points)
```

again the intersection_list_method that I was looping on gets erased and a new one is created but I want to loop on each point in that list instead and see if the function would return that list for every point in intersection_list_method till it ends

Any help?

Comment: The first obvious problem is that `for points in intersection_list_method:
    return find_new_int(node_in_ex, points)` is going to `return` as soon as you get the first value, meaning you never do the rest of the loop. (And that's your only recursive call, so presumably it's the one you're having trouble with.) What are those two lines _supposed_ to be doing?

Comment: @abarnert  So I have to find an intersection between a node who's radius I get from the method :
    intersection_rand_point(wall_coordinates[0], wall_coordinates[1],     node_in_ex-1, old_inters)

and then I return the list of wall intersections with walls around that wall with the calculated radius.

What my problem is for example if the first point in intersection's power reached from another node is < Power Sensitivity I have to loop on the next point in the intersection_list_method to find a new radius and hence get another intersection points but I can't since it only stops at 1st node

Comment: Well, yes, it stops at the first node because you `return` once for every node, and once you `return` for the first node, that's the end of the function. If you need to do something for every node and somehow aggregate the results of all those calls, you need to explain what that something is. For example, if you just want to, say, return a list of them, you can just `append` onto that list in the loop and then `return` the list once the loop is done.

Comment: No my problem here is different.
I want it to stop for the first node that I find have a list of intersection having one point of intersection in that list who's power is greater than that an original node.
That's what I did here :
   ` for points in intersection_list_method:
                if cal_pow_rec_plndwall(node_in_ex, points) >     Power_Sensitivity:
                    return intersection_list_method`
But if it didn't find a point which power > power sensitivity in THAT list I want it to again call the same function on each point in That list again till it returns something.

Comment: OK, then you just need an `if` inside the loop that checks the return value, and only returns it if it's "something". Let me try to explain in an answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help. There's a lot of reasonably complex stuff in this question that's almost certainly not relevant to the question, but anyone who wants to try to answer has to either reason through all of it, or just guess what isn't relevant and hope they guess right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does this:

```
for points in intersection_list_method:
    return find_new_int(node_in_ex, points)
```

But what you want is:

> But if it didn't find a point which power > power sensitivity in THAT list I want it to again call the same function on each point in That list again till it returns something.

Assuming the opposite of "returns something" is "returns `None`", that would look like this:

```
for points in intersection_list_method:
    result = find_new_int(node_in_ex, points)
    if result is not None:
        return result
```

Comment: But what if the function doesn't return something is it None as an output?

Comment: That's want to occur you're absolutely right but I want to tweak a bit what you just wrote to if it finished this list of :
`intersection_list_method' without returning a result and also returning None also to get the list outputed from the each point and also loop on them and do the same thing till it returns a result that is not None.
Like a recursive method.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: If you fall off the end of a function without a `return` statement, yes, the return value is `None`. You don't _have_ to use `None` here of course; you just need to have some way of signaling "I have something to return, and here's what it is" from "I have nothing to return". But the default `None` return is a convenient way to do that whenever `None` isn't a valid "something to return".

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: I don't really understand your second comment. It looks like you're asking how to do exactly what I explained and showed how to do in the answer.  The answer is looping on each `points`, recursively calling the function until it returns a result that is not `None`. If that's what you want, then just do that.

Comment: What im saying is what if the result keeps on outputing None so the loop will go through each point in intersection_list_method till it ends and the result will still be None.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: If you've recursed over all of the points and all of them returned `None`, then you return `None`. And if that bubbles all the way up to the top of the stack, then the whole thing returns `None`. Which means nothing was found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76524/discussion-between-mahmoud-ayman-and-abarnert).

Comment: but I don't want ever None to be outputed from the function because it is possible always for a result to be outputed instead of None because the radius keeps on decreasing till I find a point with power> power sensitivity but I want the algorithm to loop on each point see if there is a result which is not None then return it and if not then take the list of points of intersections of this function and loop on the points in it to find a result which is not None

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory. Your recursion depends on the fact that not every call has something to return. But now you're insisting that every call must have something to return. Those can't both be true. Either that, or you're explaining something very wrong. In that case, instead of trying to explain it in English, do what I said in the first place: come up with an MCVE that clearly demonstrates your problem without all the irrelevant complexity and edit your question.

Comment: I can't view my new written code here but i've replaced what you've written :
`for points in intersection_list_method:
    result = find_new_int(node_in_ex, points)
    if result is not None:
        return result`
instead of the last 2 lines in my code and it says the maximum number of loops or function calls has been reached without returning anything.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: How deep do you expect your recursion to go? Python can only handle a fixed recursion depth (default 1000), and doesn't do tail-call elimination, so if that's the problem, you pretty much have to manually transform your algorithm into iterative form (i.e., a loop with an explicit stack or two). If, on the other hand, you weren't expecting it to go too deep, then you have the recursive equivalent of an infinite loop—you're not reducing your case to a smaller case each time you recurse.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: And again, if you want something more than generalities, please reduce your problem to an MCVE instead of expecting someone to read, reason through, and debug all of your code. (And, if it's a new problem rather than the one you started with, ask a new question, don't try to get extra answers in comments.)

Comment: sorry im still new to this site I don't know much my way around it so please excuse me.